# Convert a HANDLE to File Descriptor

Tags: c++, windows, openssl, named-pipes, handle

I have a HANDLE like that:

```
HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(...)
```

Is possible to convert the *hPipe* to a *File Descriptor* (int)?

I need this because I have implemented in C++ a code to work with TLS using the OpenSSL. This is working like a charm with TCP sockets, but I really need use it over Namedpipe.

The OpenSSL's function [SSL_set_fd(SSL *ssl, int fd)](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_set_fd.html) accepts just *FileDescriptor* that is a *int*, and not a *HANDLE*.

**Note:** I also tried use the below function, but doesn't worked (return 3):

```
int fd = _open_osfhandle(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(hPipe), 0);
```

Comment: Did you call `ConnectNamedPipe` first?  It might not be possible to create a file descriptor for a unconnected pipe.

Comment: Yes, I called "ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL)" first, and then the "_open_osfhandle(...)".

Comment: To be more specific, I'm using the Microsoft's example [Multithreaded Pipe Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and I'm calling the "_open_osfhandle(...)" one line above the first "ReadFile(..)".

Comment: That example uses PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE and PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE, which could also be a problem, try changing them?

Comment: Also, Visual Studio includes the source for the runtime library (IIRC) so you could step into the function and see where it's having trouble.

Comment: I tried to use "PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT", but the _open_osfhandle() still returning "3". Debugging the _open_osfhandle() it appears to be fine.. but When I call "SSL_accept()" from OpenSSL, it fails..

Comment: "(return 3)".  Congratulations, it worked.  Failure is indicated with -1.  The odds that the openssl library you use is using the same CRT as the rest of your program, no congratulations there.

Comment: Do you know what I need do to fix that?

Comment: So, we've established that the problem is in SSL_accept, not in _open_osfhandle?  Have you stepped into SSL_accept?

Comment: I'm unable to step into SSL_accept(), because the OpenSSL is a library, so when I try "step into" the SSL_accept(), the debugger has a behavior like "Step Over".

Comment: The source code for OpenSSL is available so you could build it yourself if you need to.  I imagine they also have their own forums, so it might be worth asking there.

Comment: Are you using cygwin?  This old post suggests that the 3 is a bad FD and the root problem is an incompatibility between MS's runtime and cygwin.  http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware3/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=90500

Answer (score 4):

The `3` you're getting back isn't an error, it's the file descriptor handle. If you look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-osfhandle) you'll see that it returns `-1` for failure, otherwise the return value is a file descriptor.

Comment: Yes, so the strange behavior is on the OpenSSL ?

Comment: What strange behavior? Your question asks how to get a file descriptor from a HANDLE?

Comment: When I use the file descriptor returned from "_open_osfhandle()" on the OpenSSL, "SSL_accept()" return "-1" and report the error "SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL", so there is a problem with the "File descriptor"